# Hide All But One Item In A Div Upon Tree Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am loading all content on a page at once. Upon a selection of the tree I want to show only 1 grid. What my code is doing is not totally getting rid of the hidden grid nor moving the selected grid to the top (probably because the hidden grid is not totally gone I assume)

The code below seems to hide everything then keep "gridWrapper2" visible but the table in it is hidden.

How do I modify the following line of code to hide all the contents but whats in the specified id. In other words dont hide any tag thats nested in "gridWrapper2"

```
$('#contents div').not("#gridWrapper2").hide();
```

Here is where I am using the code

```
$(function() {

        $("span.dynatree-edit-icon").live("click", function(e) {
        alert("Edit " + $.ui.dynatree.getNode(e.target));
      });
      $("#tree").dynatree({
        onActivate: function(node) {

        $('#contents div').not("#gridWrapper2").hide();

          $("#info").text("You activated " + node);
        },


        children: [{
          title: "Item 1"
        }, {
          title: "Folder 2",
          isFolder: true,
          children: [{
            title: "grid2"
          }, {
            title: "grid"
          }]
        }, {
          title: "Item 3"
        }]
          });



 <body>

<div class="container-fluid text-left">    
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav" id="tree">



    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" id="contents"> 


    <div id="gridWrapper">   <table id="grid"></table> </div>
     <div id="gridWrapper2">  <table id="grid2"></table> </div>
         </div>

         <div id="info"> </div>
            </div>      
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: look at your `.dynatree()` is not closing correctly. Do you have some errors in your console?

Comment: Do you have your JavaScript in a script tag?

Comment: Yes I dont think this is a syntax error I am just trying to show whats relavant to save room I have other stuff in the script tag as well

Comment: It would help everyone if you could create jsFiddle to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution

```
$("#contents > *").css('display','none');
  $("#gridWrapper2").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure contents inside table are in proper/valid html. See below example for more info. `display:none` will be applied to `table` tag & only valid html inside it could be hidden everything else would come out of it if not valid.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tree").click(function() {
    $('#contents table').not("#grid2").not("#grid4").hide();

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid text-left">
  <div class="row content">

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8" id="contents">

    <table id="grid">
      <tr>
        <td>grid</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="grid2">
      <tr>
        <td>grid2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="grid3">grid3</table>
    <table id="grid4">grid4</table>
  </div>

  <div id="info"></div>
</div>
</div>
<button id="tree">Tree</button>
```

Comment: Its a jqgrid im hiding I have to use the html I have I think

Comment: then use `jqgrid` API to hide grid instead of css style.

Comment: I am not sure too but you need to visit jqgrid lib's site & search for the API something like `hidegrid` or `gridhidden`